# Yii: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Im currently working with Yii and i ran into a small problem.
With the widget Typeahead from Yiistrap [Link for widget](http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/widgets?sort=firstName#typeahead).
It seems the jQuery gets included multiple times, 2 times before the include of bootstrap.js and one after the include.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'typeahead'
```

How can i stop Yii from displaying this error?

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbTypeAhead', array('name' => 'Invoice[i_name]','value' => CHtml::encode($model->i_name),'source' => $model->getContactsList(), 'updater' => 'contactDetailsAjax', 'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'vert-inputs', 'placeholder' => $labels['i_name'], 'size'=>60, 'maxlength'=>255,'autocomplete'=>'off' ),)); echo $form->error($model,'i_name');?>

<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
jQuery('#Invoice_i_name').typeahead({'source':['Jordan Eisenburger'],'items':8,'minLength':1,'updater':contactDetailsAjax});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Prevent Jquery being included 2 times, that usually solves most of the javascript problems.

Comment: How could i do that??

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then it already registers jquery it for you, why you you register jquery again? See the Bootstrap.php file in components of the extension to see how it gets registered.